# Corona SDK Orbiting object change direction

Tags: physics, coronasdk, orbit

I have the following code:

```
deg = 0.0;
local function onTouch(event)
   if(event.yStart >= event.y) then
      deg = deg + 10;
   elseif(event.yStart <= event.y) then
      deg = deg -10;
   end  

   rads = deg * (math.pi /180.0);
   x = 100.0 * math.cos(rads);
   y = 100.0 * math.sin(rads);
   rect.x = magnet.x + x;
   rect.y = magnet.y + y;
end
```

It in a way works, but it does not work perfectly. What I am trying to do is when the user drags up the object will rotate clockwise. when the user drags down, the object rotates counter-clock wise (by rotate I mean orbits another object).

The issue I am having is that deg keeps incrementing up/down when the user drags up or down. so when changing directions it will have to increment all the way down to 0 effectively to change directions. I can not figure out how to affectively reset variable deg without screwing the position of the object.

Thank ahead of time.

**EDIT**

After looking at the code Ive come to realize that the problem is **NOT** what i have stated above. The issue is that when i change direction the event.yStart does not reset!

so what happens, assume I start 200px, when i drag up the will increment up as long as i stay above 200px (whether i drag up or down. And wont start decrementing until I go below 200px.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
deg = 0.0;
local prevPosY = 0
local function onTouch(event)
   if event.phase == "began" then
      prevPosY = event.y
   end
   if(event.y >= prevPosY) then
      deg = deg + 10;
   elseif(event.y <= prevPosY) then
      deg = deg -10;
   end  
   prevPosY = event.y

   rads = deg * (math.pi /180.0);
   x = 100.0 * math.cos(rads);
   y = 100.0 * math.sin(rads);
   rect.x = magnet.x + x;
   rect.y = magnet.y + y;
end
```

Comment: Thanks @Doğancan Arabacı but this has the same issue as before (albeit better code) and it DEF helped me realize what the error actually was!

Comment: your code worked actually and your logic was fine, you were just using the wrong variable in the if statements (instead of event.yStart it should be event.y.

Answer (score 0):

```
deg = 0.0;
prevY = 0;
local function onTouch(event)
  if event.phase == "began" then
      prevY = event.y
   end
   if(event.y >= prevY) then
      deg = deg + 10;
   elseif(event.y <= prevY) then
      deg = deg -10;
   end  
   prevY = event.y

   rads = deg * (math.pi /180.0);
   x = 100.0 * math.cos(rads);
   y = 100.0 * math.sin(rads);
   rect.x = magnet.x + x;
   rect.y = magnet.y + y;
end
```